# What are some uses for an old Quikrete?

Tags: mortar

I have a leftover bag of Quikrete that has turned into solid rock. It was stored for several years in a damp garage. Lesson learned.

I am thinking of using it as a step base on my new shed outside. Does anyone know of any possible downsides for this use?

It does not seem like the rain could dissolve it into the lawn, but it’s something that I have thought about.

Thanks

Comment: It might feel solid, but quite able to break apart when a lawyer steps on it.

Comment: @crip659 yeah, with this work we all worry about inspectors, children and lawyers... an interesting launch for a joke "There was this kid, an inspector and a lawyer wandering through Peter's home at the gates of heaven, when...."

Comment: Will make a good 40 to 80 pound paper weight.

Comment: Trebuchet ammo?

Comment: Paint it matte black and write ''ACME' and '80 lbs' on the side in white. Add Looney Tunes characters to taste. Couldn't resist!

Comment: I was gonna VTC but liked the comments so much that I decided to leave it as is.

Comment: @JACK even if it's closed the entertaining comments will remain. _hint hint_

Comment: You can use them to hold down your garbage cans on a windy day until they're picked up by local trash collection.

Comment: I know what MythBusters would do!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Stress until failure .. lol

Comment: @FreeMan  Why would you possibly hint that I'd make an entertaining comment??

Comment: @CarlWitthoft *"When in doubt... C4."*

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes people pour a bag of cement without mixing it with water into a post hole, or they stack bags of cement, unopened, to build a wall. The moisture in the damp air (as in your case), surrounding soil or from the rain then provides the necessary H20 for curing.

While these are neat tricks for uncritical applications, you should generally not use improperly mixed cement, mortar or concrete.

**It will generally not have predictable strength and can thus not be rated for any specific use.**

Should you be inclined to provide it with a purpose in life, you could first test its strength with a (sledge) hammer.

For this reason I generally immediately return unused bags, and never keep any around the house as a hedge against inflation. Now, building lumber is an entirely different story.

Comment: Here's a thought... will the center still be powdery? Hardened concrete will be waterproof (more or less, considering the source is probably air humidity and therefore not exactly the ideal mixture), so the chemical process should eventually stop propagating inward.

Comment: @MiG depends on humidity/moisture and time. I've seen fully hardened bags, "shelled" bags (thick hard shell but brittle in the middle), and "crusted" bages (feels hardened but is concrete that's still fine for use)